# No playback from AVPlayer after app returns from a suspended state

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayeritem, avqueueplayer

I have an AVQueuePlayer which is working as expected except for after returning from a suspended state.

It's playing a HLS audio stream. The logic for my pause button is very simple

```
isPlaying ? player?.play() : player?.pause()
```

I've checked the state of the player and the currentItem, all of which say it's "playing". But the audio does not progress or playback

```
player.rate = 1
player.currentItem.asset.isPlayable = true
player.status == readyToPlay
player.currentItem.status == readyToPlay
```

I'm also setting the session with:

```
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: [])
    try session.setActive(true, options: [])
} catch {
    print("Failed to set session active")
}
```

[image: AVPlayer won't resume after this]

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated. Do I need to keep track of the app entering a suspended state and reload the AVPlayerItem?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to keep track of the app entering a suspended state and reload the AVPlayerItem?

It is not suspension of the app that you need to keep track of; it's *interruption* of the audio session. AVAudioSession provides a notification for exactly this purpose.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions

Comment: Thanks @matt. I had tried the interruption handler and I do see it fires after coming back from suspension. I do have it working but it feels a bit hacky. I'm grabbing the current elapsed time, reinitialising the player and seeking to to the elapsed time.

Comment: I don't see why that's hacky. You were streaming and everything got hosed, so obviously you have to do _something_ to get going again.